# How to change discord-xp from giving XP per message to giving XP per minute?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The bot gives random XP between 50 and 100 points every random message, which is really slow. Having XP per minute would be better.

This is the code that gives XP, from levels.js in [discord-xp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-xp):

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 50;
    console.log(randomXp);
    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`<:GG:807231058507464735> ${message.author}, you just leveled up to **level ${user.level}!** Keep going!`);
    }
});
```

I've tried to fit

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 
const LevelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: { type: String },
  guildID: { type: String },
  xp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  level: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
  last_message: 0,
});
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Levels', LevelSchema);
```

and

```
if (Date.now() - levels.last_message > 60000) {
    const randomXp = levels.xp += random.int(15, 25);
    levels.last_message = Date.now();
}
```

in there, but it's not quite doing what I want.

Comment: And the code you have tried to solve your problem with is..? (*"Please rewrite this code for me so it does what I want"* is not a question.)

Comment: I have tried using:
if (Date.now() - levels.last_message > 60000) {
       const randomXp = levels.xp += random.int(15, 25);
        levels.last_message = Date.now();

levels.js is a file in discord-xp which has all the data, here are its contents: https://pastebin.pl/view/23d4914a

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Mongoose is really necessary. I would start with something like this.

```
const checkpoint = {};

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const authorKey = message.author.id + '|' + message.guild.id;

    if (!(authorKey in checkpoint)) checkpoint[authorKey] = Date.now();
    const minutes = Math.floor((Date.now() - checkpoint[authorKey]) / 60000);
    if (!minutes) return; else checkpoint[authorKey] = Date.now();

    // add a random XP amount for each minute (better than `minutes * random.int(15, 25)`)
    let xpEarned = 0;
    for (let m = 0; m < minutes; m++) xpEarned += random.int(15, 25);

    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, xpEarned);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`<:GG:807231058507464735> ${message.author}, you just leveled up to **level ${user.level}!** Keep going!`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, ty for the answer but It dosent seem to work. Can u please explain what const checkpoint is for or what it does?

Comment: @Dillan I have no idea what "doesn't seem to work" even means. Maybe you should be more specific? `checkpoint` saves the time of the last message per guild and user. I thought that would become clear from reading the code.